# Basic java. Event not passing value from textfield to label on button click

Tags: java, swing

This is pretty basic, but I can't get to pass the value from the textfield to the label. On clicking on the button, the value is taken from the textfield and written in the label. It is all commented

package windows;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FirstWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        //defining the objects          

            private JButton jboton;
            private JTextField jtexto;
            private JLabel jlabel;

        // constructor



                public FirstWindow(){                       
                super("mi ventana");
                this.setSize(400,400);
                definirVentana();
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setVisible(true);

            }



             public void definirVentana(){

            //define how components are laid out

            this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            //now let's instantiate the objects above
            JButton jboton = new JButton("Press me");
            JTextField jtexto = new JTextField(20);
            JLabel jlabel = new JLabel();

            //and now we add them to the window
            this.add(jboton);
            this.add(jtexto);
            this.add(jlabel);
            jboton.addActionListener(this);

        }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource() == jboton){            
                jlabel.setText(jtexto.getText()) ;

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You're likely getting a NullPointerException because you're shadowing your variables. Solution: don't do this. Declare your jlabel variable only **once**, in the class, and don't re-declare it in a method or constructor.

Comment: Please have a look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783998/why-would-i-be-getting-a-null-pointer-exception-with-gui-input-and-listener-meth/7784015#7784015) for more on this.

Comment: you are right, it solved it. What do I do now? do you want to write the answer and I check it?

Comment: This question has been asked so many times that I've already closed it as a duplicate. Consider up-voting any similar questions/answers that has helped you understand or solve this.

Comment: hi..You have jtexto and jlabel defined twice. one local to method definirVentana...which sets the text and label to your frame but your actionPerformed doesn't see that objects...it is refering to your private objects definied in class... remove declaration of objects inside definiraventana

Comment: ok, I am truly sorry, I couldn't spot the underlying error, only the description of the effect so I didnt know how to find the answer. I have upvoted the answer.

Comment: No need to apologize. I've found the duplicate for you. This is a common newbie error, one that you'll likely never do again in the future.